# Cannot install gnome-shell extension on Ubuntu 18.10 with Unity

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Just got a new pc, I've installed 18.10 and Unity, I'm in the process of setting it up to my liking and adding all the apps etc I'm already using on my old PC (also running 18.10 with Unity).

I've used a little app called "force quit" for years, it needs GNOME shell to work, but I cant install GNOME shell, I keep getting the error

> Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.

in Firefox when trying to install it.

I've done a lot of searching and found nothing that helps. Strangely I've even read a few comments that say you cant use GNOME shell with Unity, which is weird as I've been using it with Unity since Unity came out in 2011.

Can someone help? I can't understand how I can install it one one pc running Ubuntu 18.10 and Unity but not on another.

Comment: The error message sounds reasonable and valid as you have Unity, not GNOME and GNOME extensions are written for GNOME shell. *How* did you install the extension on the old PC in the first place?

Comment: Absolutely no idea - as I ve said, I ve been using it all the time I ve been using Unity (thats on 3 different pcs and on every version of ubuntu since 10.10). I cant remember what I did in 2010 to install it or in 2012 when I got a different pc or in 2015 when I got another one. I do remember installing gnome shell via a browser plugin within the last few years, again too long ago to re/member why I did, but it wasnt to get force quit to work, cos I ve been using it with unity since 2010.

Comment: I m also using Tweaks on Ubuntu Unity which is a gnome app, it reports that gnome shell is not running (but it IS installed as I ve just installed it, its just not running), Firefox reports that also. When Unity was the default desktop environment Ubuntu still used some gnome based stuff, it wasnt totally gnome free. I just cant understand why suddenly I cant use it, but I managed to on 3 previous installs.

Comment: Got to the bottom of this - in software centre if I search "Force Quit" it comes up with a Gnome Shell extension with a description that sounds exactly like the "Force Quit" option I ve had in Unity for the last 9 years. But after a lot of searching I ve found out its a script that adds it, nothing to do with Gnome shell (although its some sort of shell cos it has ".sh" in it). Guess I got confused cos the Gnome shell Force Quit button sounds exactly like what I was talking about and its a also a shell script, plus it was nearly 4 years ago I added it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Got to the bottom of this - in software centre if I search "Force Quit" it comes up with a Gnome Shell extension with a description that sounds exactly like the "Force Quit" option I ve had in Unity for the last 9 years. But after a lot of searching I ve found out its a script that adds it, nothing to do with Gnome shell (although its some sort of shell cos it has ".sh" in it). Guess I got confused cos the Gnome shell Force Quit button sounds exactly like what I was talking about and its a also a shell script, plus it was nearly 4 years ago I added it. :)